# Raising waterheater on bricks to gain clearance under

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

I was wondering if it's recommended (against) raising a waterheater on bricks to gain clearance under, which is desirable in my case to clean the air intake? The waterheater will be sitting on a platform stack consisting of a 7" tall pallet made of 2x6 and 3/4" plywood (to raise it above a drain riser coming from the floor) and in a drain pain. The legs on the heater are about only as tall as the pan is deep, making it difficult to reach under with a brush to clean. Also, was thinking it would be nice if the metal legs were not corroding if left in puddles of water in the pan.

[image]

My concern was if a brick ever crumbles or something, the waterheater can be off balance, rip the plumbing fittings etc.

Comment: Great question but I can't help observing ... I'd worry about that chipboard bottom layer disintegrating long, long before the brick does!     Use exterior grade solid wood or Trex for that entire platform.

Comment: @jay613 I made lt out of scraps, one side OSB, other plywood. Should I turn the plywood side down for more water resistance?

Comment: If it will be in an indoor, dry location you can just replace the OSB with plywood and that should be fine.  Don't use OSB at all.

Comment: What's the model of the water heater?  Most have air intakes on the sides.  I've never heard of anyone cleaning underneath a water heater.  Are you sure this is necessary?

Comment: Whirlpool tech support told me that's where it was and to clean it with a brush

Answer (score 4):

If the water tank has three legs, one on each brick, go for it. If that's particle board on the bottom, I'd replace it with plywood. You might want to seal the base with a water sealer.

Comment: I made the pallet out of scraps, one side OSB, other plywood. Should I turn the plywood side down for more water resistance and OSB side up?

Comment: If it's OSB you can leave it as is.

Comment: @JACK doesn't OSB expand or soften when wet, and in this case would cause the water heater to become unbalanced?

Comment: @jay613 OSB is better than plywood for moisture control. We're not talking particle board but OSB. It's made with those resin cocktails that are great for strength and water resistance. The water heater wouldn't become unbalanced if it had three legs and each one was on a brick (why I asked about the legs as the OP stated).